# How to change plot size in nltk.plot()

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, jupyter, ipython

I'm following along the NLTK book and would like to change the size of the axes in a lexical dispersion plot:

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import inaugural
cfd = nltk.ConditionalFreqDist(
            (target, fileid[:4]) # "[:4]" slices only the years of the speeches
            for fileid in inaugural.fileids()
            for word in inaugural.words(fileid)
            for target in ["liberty", "equality", "brotherhood"]
            if word.lower().startswith(target))
```

Because it gets **very crowded** otherwise:

`cfd.plot(title="French ideals in US-American speeches through time")`

[image]

the `__doc__` doesn't seem to mention it:

```
print(cfd.plot.__doc__)

        Plot the given samples from the conditional frequency distribution.
        For a cumulative plot, specify cumulative=True.
        (Requires Matplotlib to be installed.)

        :param samples: The samples to plot
        :type samples: list
        :param title: The title for the graph
        :type title: str
        :param conditions: The conditions to plot (default is all)
        :type conditions: list
```

And I think there is nothing on it in the [NLTK documentation](http://www.nltk.org/py-modindex.html#cap-p),nor the [matplotlib documentation](https://matplotlib.org/2.0.2/api/pyplot_api.html) (where I figured the plot functionality comes from)

Comment: Try [creating a figure of appropriate size](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332289/how-do-you-change-the-size-of-figures-drawn-with-matplotlib) before calling plot().

Comment: Hei @Emre, thanks for your answer. `nltk.ConditionalFreqDist()` does not have a `.figure()` method, and [in the code](https://github.com/nltk/nltk/blob/2c1966bb469d8a279d82e257a10d6c9da7ebc8e0/nltk/probability.py) (check out line 1781) I found that `.plot()` doesn't accept any figure-size related `**kwargs` (from what I can tell, but that's also what the `pyplot.plot()` [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.plot) seems to suggest..?).

After reading nltk's code, I added `linewidth=1`, which makes the lines a bit slimmer, but the original issue remains.

Answer (score 5):

Try something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(30, 20))  # the size you want

# your code goes here
```